# Find logs of previous pods

Tags: kubernetes

We had a system outage, service was unresponsive and I restarted the service with `kubectl rollout restart sts myservice` and it worked. However, I want to look at the logs to see a cause of the problem. When I try `kubect logs --previous myservice-0` it says 'previous terminated container "mycontainer" in pod "myservice-0" not found'. Is there a way to find the logs before the restart? I tried to look at the dead docker containers (`docker ps -a`), there are containers exited 6 month ago, but no recently exited containers of my service, why is so?

Comment: `but no recently exited containers of my service, why is so` - because kubelet removed them.

Comment: I do not know, I just executed `rollout restart`. I am surprised myself why it no trace of previous container exits (at least I cannot find it anymore).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest the following reading: [The Complete Guide to Kubernetes Logging](https://sematext.com/guides/kubernetes-logging/):

> In Kubernetes, when pods are evicted, crashed, deleted, or scheduled
> on a different node, **the logs from the containers are gone**. The system
> cleans up after itself. Therefore you lose any information about why
> the anomaly occurred.

Also, as per [Logging Architecture](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/):

> If you want to access the application's logs if a container crashes; a
> pod gets evicted; or a node dies, [...] you need a separate backend to
> store, analyze, and query logs. Kubernetes does not provide a native
> storage solution for log data. Instead, there are many logging
> solutions that integrate with Kubernetes.

Some example of those log aggregation solutions are:

- The [ELK Stack](https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elk-stack) (Elasticsearch, Logstash, Kibana)
- The [EFK Stack](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install_config/aggregate_logging.html) (Elasticsearch, Fluentd, Kibana)